# Generating a perfect hash function given known list of strings?

Tags: algorithm

Suppose I have a list of N strings, known at compile-time.

I want to generate (at compile-time) a function that will map each string to a distinct integer between 1 and N inclusive.  The function should take very little time or space to execute.

For example, suppose my strings are:

```
 {"apple", "orange", "banana"}
```

Such a function may return:

```
f("apple") -> 2
f("orange") -> 1
f("banana") -> 3
```

What's a strategy to generate this function?

I was thinking to analyze the strings at compile time and look for a couple of constants I could mod or add by or something?

The compile-time generation time/space can be quite expensive (but obviously not ridiculously so).

Comment: Why don't you use well known hash function like murmur2 and then mod the result by `N`?

Comment: @NiyokoYuliawan: This wouldn't be perfect would it?  We don't want to have any collisions.  For any two distinct strings a, b: f(a) must not equal f(b)

Comment: I think this ought to solve your problem http://burtleburtle.net/bob/hash/perfect.html (if I understand it correctly).

Comment: [`gperf`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gperf/manual/gperf.html)?

Comment: Note: `int f(char *s) { return *s & 3; }` works for these fruit.

Comment: @chux: Correct, so the question is how to, likewise, programmatically generate such a function for an arbitrary list of strings (and not just this particular list).

Comment: @AmiTavory: It's not really language specific.  I mean by "compile-time" the work to find the function for a given list of strings.  "run-time" is the cost of executing the generated function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you have *m* distinct strings, and let *a<sub>i, j</sub>* be the *j*th character of the *i*th string. In the following, I'll assume that they all have the same length. This can be easily translated into any reasonable programming language by treating *a<sub>i, j</sub>* as the null character if *j ≥ |a<sub>i</sub>|*.

The idea I suggest is composed of two parts:

1. Find (at most) *m - 1* positions differentiating the strings, and store these positions.
2. Create a perfect hash function by considering the strings as length-*m* vectors, and storing the parameters of the perfect hash function.

---

Obviously, in general, the hash function must check at least *m - 1* positions. It's easy to see this by induction. For 2 strings, at least 1 character must be checked. Assume it's true for *i* strings: *i - 1* positions must be checked. Create a new set of strings by appending 0 to the end of each of the *i* strings, and add a new string that is identical to one of the strings, except it has a 1 at the end.

Conversely, it's obvious that it's possible to find at most *m - 1* positions sufficient for differentiating the strings (for some sets the number of course might be lower, as low as log to the base of the alphabet size of *m*). Again, it's easy to see so by induction. Two distinct strings must differ at some position. Placing the strings in a matrix with *m* rows, there must be some column where not all characters are the same. Partitioning the matrix into two or more parts, and applying the argument recursively to each part with more than 2 rows, shows this.

Say the *m - 1* positions are *p<sub>1</sub>, ..., p<sub>m - 1</sub>*. In the following, recall the meaning above for *a<sub>i, p<sub>j</sub></sub>* for *p<sub>j</sub> ≥ |a<sub>i</sub>|*: it is the null character.

---

let us define *h(a<sub>i</sub>) = ∑<sub>j = 1</sub><sup>m - 1</sup>[q<sub>j</sub> a<sub>i, p<sub>j</sub></sub> % n]*, for random *q<sub>j</sub>* and some *n*. Then *h* is [known to be a universal hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_hashing#Hashing_vectors): the probability of pair-collision *P(x ≠ y ∧ h(x) = h(y)) ≤ 1/n*.

---

Given a universal hash function, there are [known constructions for creating a perfect hash function from it](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~avrim/451f11/lectures/lect1004.pdf). Perhaps the simplest is creating a vector of size *m<sup>2</sup>* and successively trying the above *h* with *n = m<sup>2</sup>* with randomized coefficients, until there are no collisions. The number of attempts needed until this is achieved, is expected 2 and the probability that more attempts are needed, decreases exponentially.

Answer (score 0):

It is simple. Make a dictionary and assign 1 to the first word, 2 to the second, ... No need to make things complicated, just number your words.

To make the lookup effective, use [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) or binary search or whatever tool your language provides.

Comment: That solution is relatively inefficient compared to a potential solution involving a couple of mods / adds.  For example as shown above `f(char *s) { return *s & 3; }` takes in the order of a couple of nanoseconds, whereas the lookup in the trie could take as much as 100s of nanoseconds.

Comment: Well, it depends. Obviously it is slower than mixing few constants, but if the hashing function needs to iterate through the whole string, the trie will not perform much worse (if well implemented). And if the alphabet is limited, then it can be implemented using arrays and the performance will be about the same as anything else. Benefit of this aproach is in simplicity and universality. Depends on the application whether it is good enough or not.